# Dynamodbclient unknown exception

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

What could be wrong with below code? Error thrown when executing `dynamoDbClient.executeStatement(request)`

Tried several ways to find the issue :(

Error: software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: An unknown operation was requested. (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: c20c2e4e-a2b9-4d9e-9405-c9f3a2505900)

> ```
> String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM policies WHERE pk=?";
> List<AttributeValue> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
> AttributeValue att1 = AttributeValue.builder()
>                 .s(policyIds.stream().findFirst().get())
>                 .build();
> parameters.add(att1);
> ExecuteStatementRequest request = ExecuteStatementRequest.builder().statement(sqlStatement).parameters(att1).build();
> ExecuteStatementResponse response = dynamoDbClient.executeStatement(request);
> ```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/example_dynamodb_BatchExecuteStatement_section.html

Comment: Are you trying this against DynamoDB Local?

Comment: Yes, it's dynamodb local

Comment: Curious if you tried the same request against the original DynamoDB?